# Loop and pagination doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination

I'm in trouble

I've a wordpress site, where i'vent a category.php template.

In my index.php where i show the custom loop if in_category:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if( in_category( array('peliculas','accion','animacion','aventuras','belico','ciencia-ficcion','comedia','drama','fantastico','romance','terror','thriller') ) ){
    get_template_part('loop', 'peliculas');
}?>
<?php if ( in_category(array('musica','ambiente','bachata','blues','country','cuarteto','cumbia','dance','dubstep','electronica','heavy-metal','hip-hop','house','jazz','pop','reggae','reggaeton','rock-nacional','rock-internacional','salsa','soul','tecno') ) ){
    get_template_part('loop', 'musica');
}?>
<?php if ( in_category(array('software') ) ) {
    get_template_part('loop', 'software');
}?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

All loops are same, showing post by title category:

```
    <?php $currentCategory = single_cat_title("", false);
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $query = array(
     'category_name' => $currentCategory,
     'paged'=> $paged,
     'posts_per_page' => '18',
     'order' => 'DESC'
    );
$page = new WP_Query( $query );
?>
 <?php if ( $page->have_posts() ) : while ( $page->have_posts() ) : $page->the_post(); ?>

//loop items
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php pagination_links(); ?>
```

The problem? The page is always displayed!
Can any help me?

More info if you can see the problem:
Category: Peliculas.
Post per page: 18
Link: http://www.megadw.com/categoria/peliculas/accion/

Thanks so much to read!

Comment: You need to check your wordpress setting.

Comment: Wow, this appears to have worked.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set proper parameters in `pagination_links()` function.

```
<?php
                $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                global $wp_query;

                $page_args = array(
                    'base' => add_query_arg('paged', '%#%'),
                    'format' => '?page=%#%',
                    //'total' => $post_categories->max_num_pages,
                    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                    'current' => $page,
                    'show_all' => False,
                    'end_size' => 1,
                    'mid_size' => 2,
                    'prev_next' => True,
                    'prev_text' => __('Â« Previous'),
                    'next_text' => __('Next Â»'),
                    'type' => 'plain',
                    'add_args' => False,
                    'add_fragment' => '',
                    'before_page_number' => '',
                    'after_page_number' => '');

                echo paginate_links($page_args);
                ?>
```

Try this.

Comment: Yes, the pagination_links is fine, in function.php. Its solved, with solution of @hardik solanki